# How to disable a button in flutter untill all Text feilds are filled

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, flutter-layout, dart-ui

I have a registration form with multiple text feilds and a Radio button and a birthdate picker. I want to disable the submit button untill the user key in all the required feilds.
I managed to do something but it only validates one text feild.

```
 bool activateTheButton =false;

@override
 initState(){
   super.initState();
    nameController = TextEditingController();

    nameController.addListener(() {
      final activateTheButton = nameController.text.isNotEmpty;
      setState(() => this.activateTheButton = activateTheButton);

   ......................
ElevatedButton( onPressed: activateTheButton
             ? (){

         }: null,

 }
```

How can I make it so that all the textfeilds along with the radio button and date of birth must have data first then activate button?

your help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a variable that enables/disables the button:

```
bool _disabled = true;
```

Use `IgnorePointer` and `Opacity` for the button:

```
IgnorePointer(
  ignoring: _disabled;
  child: Opacity(
    opacity: _disabled ? 0.5 : 1.0,
    child: YourButton(...),
  )
)
```

You are going to have controllers for each TextFields;

```
TextEditingController _controllerOne;
TextEditingController _controllerTwo;
```

Use the `TextField`'s `onChanged: (value) {}` to call a method that handles the `_disabled` variable:

```
TextField(
  controller: _controllerOne,
  onChanged: (text) {
    _setDisabled();
  },
),
```

```
_setDisabled() {
   if (_controllerOne.text != "" && _controllerTwo.text != "") {
      setState(() {_disabled = false;});
   } else {
      setState(() {_disabled = true;});
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I just had to change some lines to make it work properly. 
First the button was activated when the bool was false and ignored when it was true so I had to change this line: " ignoring: !activateTheButton,
         child: Opacity(
         opacity: activateTheButton  ? 1.0 : 0.5,"
And then I changed the _setDisabled() function to: "if (Name1!.isNotEmpty && Weight1!.isNotEmpty && Height1!.isNotEmpty) {" where I declared few new strings and assigned the values to them cause some of the values I had in the feilds were numbers.
Finally I just had to flip the setState in the function.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here [How do I disable a Button in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49351648/how-do-i-disable-a-button-in-flutter)

In the same way you should enable it when you wanto to.

Comment: None of these answers is solving my issue here. As I stated, I can disable and enable the button based on one textfeild state but in my case, I have multiple tectfeilds and I want to make sure that all of them has values before enabling the button again.

Comment: Try using a static variable, or initate a class in a global object or use static members, that saves the validation status of each text field. And every time you change a text field set a proper value in it and check every time if all proprietes ar valid in order to enable the button.

Answer (score 0):

check this hope this helps

```
class ResetPasswordForm extends StatefulWidget {
const ResetPasswordForm({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

@override
_ResetPasswordFormState createState() => _ResetPasswordFormState();
}

class _ResetPasswordFormState extends State<ResetPasswordForm> {
 final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
   final TextEditingController _emailController = TextEditingController();
   final bool _isValidated = false;

String? validateEmail(String? value) {
String pattern = ValidatorRegex.emailAddress;
RegExp regex = RegExp(pattern);
if (value == null || value.isEmpty || !regex.hasMatch(value)) {
  return ValidatorString.enterValidEmail;
} else {
  setState(){
    _isValidated = true;
  }
  return null;
}
  }

 @override
  void dispose() {
_emailController.dispose();
super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Column(
  children: [
    Form(
      key: _formKey,
      child: TextFormField(
        controller: _emailController,
        validator: (value) => validateEmail(value),
      ),
    ),
    ElevatedButton(
      onPressed:_isValidated
          ? () {
              //do stuff
            }
          : null,,
      child: const Text('Reset Password'),
    ),
  ],
);
 }
 }
```

[How to disable button until text form field has valid data Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70919087/how-to-disable-button-until-text-form-field-has-valid-data-flutter)

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have seen this answer earlier but unfortunately, it doesn't give me the behavior I am looking for.